# How can I setup an Outlook notification webhook on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, webhooks, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

Currently we have subscription in Office 365. All users has access to Outlook emails. We are planning to build a batch job using Daemon or Server application (as described here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api). The reason for the batch job to be as Daemon service is because we wanted to access all user emails, filter and forward to another mail server with one app identity.

- **Question 1 : How can we grant an app in Azure to access all users emails ?**

As an alternative we could also build a webhook that is subscribed to inbound/outbound emails and once we get a notification in our system we can filter/forward to another mail server. https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/concepts/webhooks

- **Instead of building a job and calling a REST API, is there a way to
  register a webhook in Azure for all users at once and redirect the
  url to our system ?**

That will save us from building a batch job that has to run everyday to grab all incoming emails and then filter. If we can integrate a webhook all we have to build is just the filter/forward part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Webhooks are only supported for user level credentials. i.e Each user has to give the app a permission to request data on behalf of users. However, in our case, we need to get notifications for all user emails to reach our application and this is impossible to do at the time of writing (Sep 2016).

The solution we went forward is to build a batch job to pull all data. An Admin has to give an access to the application (the application will have its own identity) and make subsequent requests. For the app to identify itself, we have used X.509 certificate

We followed [this documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the specific messages with Office 365, a easy way is config the **mail flow** on the Exchange Admin Center.

For example, we can config a rule to redirect to the messages to the mailbox you wanted as below:
[image]

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-SG/library/jj657505(v=exchg.150).aspx) is the document for the mail flow rules for your reference.